# Xcode 9 / Swift 4 migration error

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I'm receiving errors when trying to automatically migrate to swift 4.

I'm getting "unexpected duplicate task" when trying to migrate a workspace with multiple targets.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same error when trying to migrate to swift 4. Check if you did enable the "New Build System (Preview)" under File > Workspace Settings. If you enabled it make sure to set it back to "Standard Build System". Did solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

**Reference From BEm answer**

I had the same problem. In my app I have three target

- Dev
- Pre
- Prod

App was running in Dev but not in Pre & Prod.

When I open my under File > Workspace Settings, I had below  (New Build System(Default))

[image]

I changed it to (Legacy Build System)

[image]

And it was a fix for me.